# Prompt a user multiple times while selecting a choice

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I'm having difficulty doing this:

1. Create a new HTML file with script tags as demonstrated in the video. Prompt the user to enter a day of the week in numerical form where 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday. Based on the user’s numerical entry, use a switch...case statement to determine the day and output the result to the console. For example, if the user inputs a 6, the output should be “Friday”.
2. Display a menu of fruits and prices to the user similar to the example below:

   ```
    1) Apple $.99
    2) Pear $.79
    3) Orange $1.19
    4) Grapes $1.49
    5) Grapefruit $1.79
    6) Kiwi $.79
    7) Apricots $1.29
   ```
3. Prompt the user twice. First, prompt the user for which fruit they’d like to purchase (1-7). Next prompt the user for how many of those fruits they want to purchase. Record these values to variables and then output the users order to the screen like this:

   ```
    10 Apples = $9.90
   ```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Switch Case Statment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Choose a fruit</h2>
        <p>1. Apple $0.99.<br/>2. Pear $0.79.<br/>3. Orange $1.19.<br/> 4. Grapes $1.49.<br/>5. Grape Fruit $1.79.<br/> 6. Kiwi $0.79.<br/> 7. Apricots $1.29.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
        //Days of the Week Start
        let daysOfWeek = prompt("Enter a numerical value for days of the week, where 1 is Sunday [1-7]");

        switch(daysOfWeek){
            case "1":
                console.log("Sunday");
                break;
            case "2":
                console.log("Monday");
                break;
            case "3":
                console.log("Tuesday");
                break;
            case "4":
                console.log("Wednesday");
                break;
            case "5":
                console.log("Thursday");
                break;
            case "6":
                console.log("Friday");
                break;
            case "7":
                console.log("Saturday");
        }
        if(daysOfWeek <=7){
            let fruit = prompt ("Choose a fruit [1-7]");
        }
        
        //Days of the week end.
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have managed to do this but the second prompt is hiding my html, so the user cant see the list of fruits.

can you help me solve the problem thanks Oswald.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the page has finished loading by executing the code in the [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event handler....I would think that would work, but it doesn't for me. So I had to add a delay with `setTimeout`, too?

```js
window.onload = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    //Days of the Week Start
    let daysOfWeek = prompt("Enter a numerical value for days of the week, where 1 is Sunday [1-7]");

    switch (daysOfWeek) {
      case "1":
        console.log("Sunday");
        break;
      case "2":
        console.log("Monday");
        break;
      case "3":
        console.log("Tuesday");
        break;
      case "4":
        console.log("Wednesday");
        break;
      case "5":
        console.log("Thursday");
        break;
      case "6":
        console.log("Friday");
        break;
      case "7":
        console.log("Saturday");
    }
    if (daysOfWeek <= 7) {
      let fruit = prompt("Choose a fruit [1-7]");
    }

    //Days of the week end.
  }, 100)
 };
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Choose a fruit</h2>
  <p>1. Apple $0.99.<br/>2. Pear $0.79.<br/>3. Orange $1.19.<br/> 4. Grapes $1.49.<br/>5. Grape Fruit $1.79.<br/> 6. Kiwi $0.79.<br/> 7. Apricots $1.29.</p>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```